# How do I test my own hand written digits or one of data from MNIST dataset using CLI

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, keras, mnist

I'm studying machine learning and I'm totaly new with this. I have given a task to **build a simple command line program that takes in a handwritten digit image,
and output prediction of which digit the computer thinks the image contains** using MNIST dataset. I found a code that user keras.

```
    from __future__ import print_function

    import keras
    from keras.datasets import mnist
    from keras.models import Sequential
    from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
    from keras.optimizers import RMSprop


    batch_size = 128
    num_classes = 10
    epochs = 20

    # the data, shuffled and split between train and test sets
    (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

    x_train = x_train.reshape(60000, 784)
    x_test = x_test.reshape(10000, 784)
    x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
    x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
    x_train /= 255
    x_test /= 255
    print(x_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
    print(x_test.shape[0], 'test samples')

    # convert class vectors to binary class matrices
    y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
    y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)
    print (tf.(orange_measurement))lis[]3

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu', input_shape=(784,)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

    model.summary()

    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
          optimizer=RMSprop(),
          metrics=['accuracy'])

    history = model.fit(x_train, y_train,
                batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs,
                verbose=1, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
    score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
    print('Test loss:', score[0])
    print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
```

after I execute this code how can I make it become simple CLI program that can receive picture and give me prediction what digit it is more likely.

as for example I saw in one youtube tutorial to determine flower(rose,daisy,dandalion, sunflower, and tulip) by obly executing in command:

```
    # In Docker
    python /tf_files/label_image.pyy /tf_files/flower_photos/daisy/21652746_cc379e0eea_m.jpg
```

after restarting docker and it'll show the confident of the computer. So what command can I use to test my own image or one imange from mnist dataset and result a prediction?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this code is learning how to identify the digits but when it's finished the model disappears. If you want to be able to use the model later you'll want to try model.save(filepath). (More information on how to save and load here:https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-save-a-keras-model)

Then you could create a separate script, image_label.py for example, that loads the model and runs the second argument through the network. You're going to need to do some preprocessing of handwritten image files to run them through a network trained for MNIST images. If you want to test it on MNIST sample images it might be a little easier.